# jquery select all LI from UL's, that not in UL element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to select all elements from `ul`, exclude `ul` with class `not-need`?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class='not-need'>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **[`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector)** or **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not)** for excluding element

```js
$('ul:not(.not-need) li').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>


<ul class='not-need'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

or

```js
$('ul').not('.not-need').find('li').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>


<ul class='not-need'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```